# Keeping track of changes in array of objects isn't working with Vue.$set

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a computed attribute 'alphabet' that contains a list of objects, the objects each contain an attribute letter (a string) and an attribute guessed (a boolean). I am trying to bind the guessed attribute to a class, however, it seems that when I try to change the guessed attribute with Vue.$set as opposed to with an equality operator (as suggested in the documentation), I still can't seem to get it to work.

I've tried setting the guessed attribute to true by default and it worked, so I can assume that the problem doesn't lie in my configuration of the css.

I've also tried printing out the alphabet object in the console, to make sure that the value actually gets changed (and it does). So I presume that the problem must be that, for some reason, the value simply isn't updated reactively in the HTML.

Here is my configuration for the list:

```html
<ul>
    <li v-for="(letter, index) in alphabet"
        v-bind:key="letter.id"
        @click="makeGuess(index)"
        v-bind:class="{guessed: letter.guessed}">{{letter.letter}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

In the last line, I am trying to hook up the guessed attribute with the class.

Here is my alphabet attribute:

```html
computed: {
    alphabet: function () {
        var objects = [];
        var letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
        letters.forEach(function (element) {
            objects.push({
                letter: element,
                guessed: false
            })
        });
        return objects;
    }
}
```

And here is my makeGuess function:

```html
methods: {
    makeGuess: function (index) {
        if (this.word.includes(this.alphabet[index].letter)) {
            this.$set(this.alphabet, index, {
                letter: this.alphabet[index].letter,
                guessed: true
            })
            console.log(this.alphabet)
        }
    }
}
```

The expected result is that the guessed gets added reactively if letter.guessed is true, but that doesn't seem to be happening. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why use a computed property here if you can simply create a data property and push the guessed letters into it? Also you can not modify a computed property directly but only its underlying value(s).

Comment: Hey, you were right, moving it from computed to data solved it. However, it seems that I can't use a function to initalize this property (it only worked for me when I manually hardcoded it with one letter, copying the code with the function returning the list of arrays didn't work, any advice on that?

Comment: Also, the reason why I want all the letters right at the beginning instead of pushing the guessed letters into it is that I want to view all the letters and only strike-through the once that the user already guessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't modify the output of a computed property. Instead you need to change the inputs for that property to include all the information you need so that it can be recomputed.

Vue will not add reactivity observers to an object/array returned by a computed property. The assumption is that such values won't be mutated so only the upstream data needs to be observed.

The simplest solution here is just to move `alphabet` into `data` rather than a computed property:

```js
data: function () {
    var letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");

    var alphabet = letters.map(function (element) {
        return {
            letter: element,
            guessed: false
        }
    });

    return {
        alphabet: alphabet
    };
}
```

If you do it like that then everything will be reactive. You don't need the computed property, nor do you need to use `$set`.

If you can't move it to a computed property, say because the letters come from a prop, then it gets a bit more complicated. In that case you need some sort of data structure to hold the guesses. e.g.

```js
data: function () {
    return {
        guessed: {}
    };
}
```

then the computed property would be:

```js
computed: {
    alphabet: function () {
        var letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
        var guessed = this.guessed;

        return letters.map(function (element) {
            return {
                letter: element,
                guessed: guessed[element]
            };
        });
    }
}
```

with `makeGuess` being:

```js
methods: {
    makeGuess: function (index) {
        var letter = this.alphabet[index].letter;

        if (this.word.includes(letter)) {
            this.$set(this.guessed, letter, true);
        }
    }
}
```